# writing too many times in a database

Tags: android, sqlite, gps, routes

I'm trying  to store in a database some GPS data that I get from a KML file using DDMS, the problem is that every time I run my program I store this data. This means that I have it stored for couple of times.  After that I have to create a route based on this GPS data stored in in Sqlite.

Now the problem is that I can't have this route right because in my database is a mess. So much data stored for too many times.Does anyone have an idea of how can I get this done right. I'm running on android 2.1

Comment: What is your expected behavior wrt database content?

Comment: Btw it is allowed to edit the question to clarify it. No need to open a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the data base initialization logic so that it stores an indicator that the data base has been initialized. (SharedPreferences is good for this.) Then test for the indicator and skip the data base initialization at start-up if the indicator shows it has already been done.

Comment: If I'm not asking too much do you have an example of database initalization using SharedPreferences cause is something I've never heard until now...I have no clue how it works.Thank you!

Comment: SharedPreferences has nothing (directly) to do with data base initialization. It's just a convenient place to store a flag that will persist between executions of your app. There are other options--see the topic [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). You could also just check that the data base exists and assume that if it does, it has also been initialized.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply INSERTing the data each time, you could switch to REPLACE instead.  This will then replace the existing data (if the data matches).  Personally, I'd change your database setup code, though.

One easy thing to use is the user_version pragma.  This allows you to get or set a database "version" for your database.  It defaults to 0, so you could check it at app start and if it is 0, initialize the DB and then set it to 1.  Subsequent app starts would then skip the database initialization.

```
PRAGMA user_version
PRAGMA user_version = 1
```